# @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient field still serialized

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, transient

I have read about @Transient for spring which :

```
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient is for ObjectMapping Framework serializations used within Spring
```

So I can use @org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient to prevent serialization to Json , However I still can persist to DB. However I'm using spring boot 2.0.4.RELEASE and when I annotate a field with transient it still gets serialized to Json !

so what am I missing here ?

Comment: Did you try to use `@JsonIgnore` annotation from `jackson`?

Comment: Yes , it works. but I wonder what is the benefit from the spring transient one

Comment: `org.springframework.data` is part of the *database persistence* framework of Spring, and doesn't apply to XML/JSON text formatting.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to serialize some specific field to JSON you have to use `@JsonIgnore` annotation for `jackson`

`@Transient` annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database only, it shouldn't work for JSON serialization